# python reverse list recursive, using only

Tags: python, list, function, recursion

I'm having problems reversing a list using recursion using only these functions:

```
def head(xs):
    return xs[0]

def tail(xs):
    return xs[1:]

def empty(xs):
    return len(xs) == 0
```

I can do this:

```
def p(xs1, xs2):
    if not empty(tail(xs1)):
        p(tail(xs1), xs2)
    xs2.append(head(xs1))

def p05(xs):
    s = []
    p(xs, s)
    return s
```

Is there a way to do it without using append()??

Comment: Don't write Haskell in Python :)

Comment: I find this problem confusing because the two answers below suggest using `+` (as was my first instinct). But for all intents and purposes, `+` is also a function! Or in any case, it causes another function (`list.__add__`) to be called. Did the author of this problem address that subtlety?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could avoid changing the list in place and instead return a new list:

```
def p(xs1, xs2):
    if not empty(tail(xs1)):
        xs2 = p(tail(xs1), xs2)
    return xs2 + [head(xs1)]

def p05(xs):
    return p(xs, [])
```

You should probably change `head()` to return a list as well:

```
def head(xs):
    return xs[:1]

def tail(xs):
    return xs[1:]
```

and 'empty' is not needed; `[]` is considered `False` in a python context. Then `p()` becomes:

```
def p(xs1, xs2):
    if tail(xs1):
        xs2 = p(tail(xs1), xs2)
    return xs2 + head(xs1)
```

Demonstration:

```
>>> p(range(5), [])
[4, 3, 2, 1, 0]
```

Comment: thank you. I'm not allowed to change the given functions, schoolwork :P

Comment: Then use `[head(xs1)]` and use the `empty()` if you *must*.

Answer (score 5):

```
def head(xs):
    return xs[0]

def tail(xs):
    return xs[1:]

def empty(xs):
    return len(xs) == 0

def reverse(xs):
    if empty(xs): return []
    return reverse(tail(xs))+[head(xs)]

xs = range(4)
print(reverse(xs))
```

yields

```
[3, 2, 1, 0]
```

Comment: one liner using ternary conditional operator:

return [] if empty(xs) else reverse(tail(xs)) + [head(xs)]